# Hitting order of sets by a Lévy process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, potential-theory, levy-processes

Let $X$ be a transient Lévy process on $\mathbb R$, and $B\subseteq \mathbb R$ a Borel set with first hitting time $T_B = \inf \left\{t>0 : X_t\in B\right\}$. For Borel $A\subseteq B$, can anything be said about
$$
\mathbb P_0(T_A < T_{B\setminus A} | T_A<\infty)?
$$
I'm really interested in any results, ideas, even gut feelings. I'd not be surprised if it's related to potential density, but I currently can't see how.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted care to explain why? If there is a problem with my question I'd like to know so that I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: Since we are on R, lets first look at the problem of exiting interval [a,b] from the left endpoint a. For Brownian motion this can be done by studying the exponential martingale and applying optional stopping theorem. See here for the Levy process's exponential martingale https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855860/exponential-martingale-lévy-process-and-stopping-times-definition-quesiton